# SideBySide error (Syst Log), executing a WindowsService devlopped with Delphi 2010, (using CoInitialize), on Windows Server 2003

Tags: delphi, ado, side-by-side

I've developed a **Windows Service coded in Delphi 2010, using ADO component.** (with **CoInitialize/CoUnintialize**).

On my station (OS:**Windows 7**) , the service works fine. 
(executing a sql requests on a database every minute (using a Timer) and sending text files by ftp)

But on the server (OS **Windows server 2003**), the service excutes the actions only one time, and then nothing more append, the service is apparently and correctly "Starded" in the service manager, but it don't do anything...It generates every minute this error in the

**Syst Log** : (in french...)

*Type de l'événement : Erreur

Source de l'événement : SideBySide

Catégorie de l'événement : Aucun

ID de l'événement : 59

Date :  11/06/2011

Heure :  15:50:18

Utilisateur : N/A

Ordinateur : VOR-WWW01

Description :

Generate Activation Context a échoué pour C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\5800aeb6\582cb976\assembly\dl3\318d7bb4\000e1f5f_a790cb01\WS100Sync.DLL. Message d'erreur de référence : L'assemblage référencé n'est pas installé sur votre système.*

and in the **App Log** :

*Type de l'événement : Erreur

Source de l'événement : Vertaris_Suivi_Tiers.exe

Catégorie de l'événement : Aucun

ID de l'événement : 0

Date :  11/06/2011

Heure :  00:55:38

Utilisateur : N/A

Ordinateur : VOR-WWW01

Description :

La description pour l'ID d'événement ( 0 ) dans la source (Vertaris_Suivi_Tiers.exe) est introuvable. L'ordinateur local n'a peut-être pas les informations de Registre ou les librairies requises pour afficher les messages émanant d'un ordinateur distant. Vous pourrez peut-être utiliser l'option /AUXSOURCE= pour récupérer cette description. Reportez-vous aux rubriques Aide et support pour plus de détails. Les informations suivantes font partie de l'événement : Erreur E/S 32.*

I've search on the web, and many SideBySide errors seem being fixed installing :
Windows Visual C++ 2005 Redistribuable
So I've installed this package but nothing changed...

Do you have any ideas or informations to help me ?...

Answer (score 0):

you can maybe try to run the core of your code: (timer + query), as a non Windows service, on win 2003. 
You will check if the error is due to win 2003 compatibility or rights on services.
Are you sure the DataSource (ODBC DSN or somehing else?) is OK in your w2003 machine?
you can maybe test it in a non win service too.

best

se

Comment: thank you for the advice, i've just tried with a simple executable and same problem... ODBC is ok because the request is correctly executed but just one time,i'm going to try on another server...